# Change css class name based on existance of variable

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to change a css class name if a variable exist on page, not sure what will be the exact code

```
<sec:accesscontrollist hasPermission="WRITE" domainObject="${biAccess}" var="biAccessEnabled" />
<c:if test="${biAccessEnabled}">
    <div class="features p1">
</c:if>
<div class="---what will be here? ---"></div>
```

[what will be here?] - here I want class name "p2" if biAccessEnabled variable is there otherwise class name "simple".... how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the conditional EL operator.

```
<div class="${biAccessEnabled ? 'p2' : 'simple'}"></div>
```